# 'hidden' property does not work with flex-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following code using flex-box

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <polymer-element name='test-flex'>
    <template>

      <style>
         .lab-flex-col-container {
           display: flex;
           flex-flow: column;
           align-content: center;
           background-color: gold;
           border-radius:5px;
           margin: 5px;
        }

        .lab-flex-col {
          display:flex;
          flex-flow:column;
          align-self:center;
          margin:5px;
        }

        .margin2 { margin: 2px; }


      </style>

      <form id='form'
        class='form'>

        <div class='lab-flex-col-container'>
           <div class='lab-flex-col' id='hidden-does-not-work' hidden>
              <input id='hidden-works' type='text'>
           </div>

           <div id='hidden-works' hidden>
              <textarea></textarea>
           </div>
           <div id='hidden-does-not-work-here-either' class='lab-flex-col' hidden>
              <button>Save</button>
           </div>

        </div>
      </form>

    </template>

    <script type="application/dart;component=1">

      import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
      import 'dart:html';


      @CustomTag( 'test-flex' )
      class TestFlex extends PolymerElement
      {

        TestFlex.created() : super.created();

        ready()
        {
          $['hidden-does-not-work'].hidden = true;
        }

        void syncDb ( Event e, var detail, var target )
        {

        }

        @override
        void enteredView()
        {
           super.enteredView();

           $['hidden-does-not-work-here-either'].hidden = true;

        }
      }

    </script>
  </polymer-element>
```

Why does the presence of the lab-flex-col class prevents the hiding of the text input?
I have tried hidden='hidden' and this does not work either.

When hidden is present as in the textarea element, it works as expected, but once the flex-box class is added, it ceases to work and the element remains visible.

Answer (score 18):

The easiest fix is to override the entire behavior with an attribute selector. No document changes needed:

```
[hidden]{
  display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mjxcrrve/

I am guessing the logic behind the default behavior is to allow overriding the "hidden" html attribute with CSS. "hidden" is more or less an implicit "display: none", so overriding the "display" style is a a natural candidate. But I agree it seems ill-thought-out that modifying pure layout should affect visibility.

Comment: So this works because the attribute selector is more specific than the class specified display value?

Comment: @ManishShrestha To be precise: it works because an attribute selector is generally more specific than a class selector (or so it has been decided in the standard). Precedence is resolved purely at the selector level. What style properties we choose to modify with them is incidental.

Answer (score 11):

This gets the job done:

```
[hidden] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Note that the `!important` part is important to prevent the `display: none` declaration from being overridden by your other CSS code.

More info: https://meowni.ca/hidden.is.a.lie.html

Answer (score 8):

Create a `.hidden` class with `display:none` and add it to your div-class instead.

HTML:

```
<div class='lab-flex-col-container'>
    <div class='lab-flex-col hidden' id='hidden-does-not-work'>
        <input id='hidden-works' type='text'>
    </div>
    <div id='hidden-works' hidden>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id='hidden-does-not-work-here-either' class='lab-flex-col hidden'>
        <button>Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lab-flex-col {
    display: flex;
}

.lab-flex-col.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mNux/3/

Answer (score 4):

Just a hint for those using polymer's `iron-list`, if the item's template encloses a flexbox div, such as:

```
<template>
    <div class="layout vertical">Your content</div>
</template>
```

just wrap the flexible div using another one, like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
         <div class="layout vertical">Your content</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

So now, `iron-list` will attach hidden to the outer div, and the row will vanish in the proper way.

By using,

```
[hidden] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

rows will be invisible but, it will still be possible to scroll over to the empty space, not quite the expected behavior.

Answer (score 4):

For the rookies like me, [the .hidden Mozilla docs has a special call out to highlight this issue:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden)

> Note: Changing the value of the CSS display property on an element
> with the hidden attribute overrides the behavior. For instance,
> elements styled display: **flex will be displayed despite the hidden
> attribute's presence.**

## Why .hidden doesn't work with display: flex

The reason this happens is because *.hidden is not the same as directly changing the CSS.*

[I put together an example codepen showing this.](https://codepen.io/joshdance-the-sans/pen/poLyyRL)

Run the code pen then inspect the `whenSignedOutSection` element after you click the buttons.

Notice that setting `whenSignedOutSection.hidden = true;` does not directly change the CSS, it adds a `div[Attributes Style]` which is less specific that the CSS telling the element to display as flex.

[image: not as specific]

To be honest, I don't quite understand what a `div[Attributes Style]` is, but I understand it is less specific than the CSS rule where you set flex which directly targets the element.

## How to fix it

So instead of using `.hidden`, add and remove a class with a `display: none` rule set to show and hide the elements.

[Harvard's answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23941712/1296746) is a good example of how to do this.

The only tricky part for beginners is you want to select the elements that have both your selector, and the new hide class. You do that by putting both selectors together with no space between them, like this:

```
.yourSelector.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Don't use a space between the two selectors like this:

```
.yourSelector .hide {
      display: none;
}
```

because instead of selecting the element that has your selector AND the class `.hide`,  the space will select the **children** of your selector that have the class `.hide`. [CSS Tricks has a short article that explains a bit more](https://css-tricks.com/whats-the-difference/).

For experienced devs this might seem too basic, but I wasted 2.5 hours on this issue today, so want to help others that find this in the future.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. Because it really explains what happened.